# Save a Word file using Cell Value as Filename

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that allows us to merge info from an online database.  I am trying to create a macro that will take the value in a specific table cell and use that to save the file in a specific directory.

I am not proficient with VBA but try to muck about with what others have done by copying code from other resources such as here.

I have found code that allows me to select the correct cell and I was able to make it work.

I found other code to save the file and I have tried to modify it to include the cell value as the file name.

```
Sub SaveAsCellContent()

    Dim Invoice As String
    
    Dim directory As String
    
    Invoice = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 5)
        
    directory = "D:\Dropbox (DRYBSMT)\~ DB Forms\Word Saves\"
    
    wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    WordDoc.SaveAs FileName = DIR & INV & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    WordDoc.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

As written I get an error **"Compile Error: Type Mismatch"**.

I have spent hours and hours trying to figure this out and I think it is time to solicit expert help.

---

What I have now, and it is working:

```
Sub SaveAsCellContent()

    Dim Invoice As String
    
    Dim Directory As String
    
    Invoice = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 5).Range.Text
    
    Invoice = Left(Invoice, Len(Invoice) - 2)
        
    Directory = "D:\Dropbox (DRYBSMT)\~ DB Forms\Word Saves\"
  
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=Directory & Invoice & "i.docx", fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
   
End Sub
```

But I am told I need to add Debug.Print. Which is where I am at now.

Comment: What are `DIR` and `INV`? They do not match the variables you are using above. You are also missing a `:` in `:=`

Comment: `FileName:=Directory & Invoice & ".docx"`

Comment: Also, where are you giving `WordDoc` and `wordApp` a value? Maybe you meant `ActiveDocument`?

Comment: Definitely the line Invoice = throws an error because Invoice is type String and the returned cell object of type cell.  Append the cell object with .range.text

Comment: Also adding empty value  checking on all values would be useful to ensure the saveas does not fail.  Then add an on error clause in case the saveas fails.

Comment: @braX, I had tried both short and long versions but must have been in between when I posted.  Thank you for catching that as well as the missing `:`.  `WordDoc` and `wordApp` were  remnants of the code I had copied.  I didn't notice a declaration for them so I thought they were VBA commands specific to MS-Word VBA.

Comment: @Boeryepes, I added `.Range.Text` to make the line `Invoice = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 5).Range.`  Text but it shows yellow in debugging but apparently works because I am now getting through to the SaveAs comand  but getting a Run-time error 5487 which is a file permissions error. `ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=Directory & Invoice & ".docx", fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument`.  The  drive is not write protected and is a local drive, albeit a Dropbox location.  But there is no error when saving manually to the location.

Comment: I tried changing the path to just the C: drive but I get an error to check if the drive is write protected etc.  I have been searching for a solution but have not found anything as yet.  The file in question is based on a template as well in case that matters.

Comment: Add a Debug.print on the filename string you are passing to saveas and manually try to save to the same

Comment: another error in the code is the FileName =. This should be FileName:=

Comment: and another issue is that the cell value includes 2 extra characters namely the end of cell characters Chr(13) & Chr(7) so you have to trim off these 2 characters by adding this line:   Invoice = Left(Invoice, Len(Invoice) - 2) // this code will fail if your filename is less than 2 characters. This fixes the 'no permission error (I copied your code to test it)

Comment: Thank you @Boeryepes, it is working now, but I don't understand where to put the Debug.print command.

Comment: I think we've helped you enough for now. and it is time for you to investigate error handling and debugging vba.  (The debug.print helps analysis).   It is now time to do some more googling and check out all the things you can do with vba.  Also using this site's search is a learning experience that is quite useful.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Boeryepes.  I did google Debug.print to try and figure it out before asking and I will continue to work on that. I value all the helped I have received from everyone here on Stackoverflow.  It is an amazing resource.  Thank you again!  I would like to make sure the final code is posted as an answer so that others can benefit from it so if you would like to post it as the answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Will do. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included all above comments in below working code example including adding an example error handler and a debug.print statement that prints the build directory + file name to the Immediate (debug) window.

```
Sub SaveAsCellContent()

Dim Invoice As String
Dim directory As String

' Get the filename that is in the 1st table in the document
Invoice = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text

' so the Invoice string is always at least 2 characters long
' because a cell's value contains the cell boundary characters
' remove the cell boundary characters as they cannot be used for the file name
Invoice = Left(Invoice, Len(Invoice) - 2)

' no file name specified
If Len(Invoice) = 0 Then
    Invoice = "default filename"
End If

' build the directory + filename to use in the saveas
directory = "D:\Dropbox (DRYBSMT)\~ DB Forms\Word Saves\"
' adding the file extension .docx is not needed
' is determined by the FileFormat parametes
Dim fileNm As Variant
fileNm = directory & Invoice

' print to the Immediate window for testing purposes
Debug.Print ("File name: " & fileNm)
   
On Error GoTo saveError
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fileNm, 
FileFormat:=WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault

saveError:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Some error occurred:" & vbCrLf & Err.Number)
    End If
End Sub
```